# Getting an error while inserting values from the tkinter GUi to the database

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite, tkinter-entry

Getting an error while inserting values from the tkinter GUi to the sqlite3 database.
Taking input from the user

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! Please supply your code.

Comment: Are you using an `Entry()` widget? If you do, then I have the answer. Otherwise, please do tell what widgets you are using, and your code would also help. Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah I'm using the entry widget!

Comment: You need to show some code that exhibits this problem, and show the actual error you are getting.

Comment: @RishiJaiswar are you having trouble getting what's inside the the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

By the tone of your question, it seems like you are having trouble accessing what is inside the text box.

An answer would be the `.get()` method. This basically allows you to access what is inside the text box.

Here is a simple code:

```py
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Example")
window.geometry("500x500")
window.configure(bg = "sky blue")
e = Entry(window, bg = "blue", fg = "orange")
e.pack()
def com1():
    acess = e.get()
    print(acess)
button1 = Button(window, text = "enter", command = com1)
button1.pack()
```

The `e.get()` is what takes the stuff inside the `Entry` widget.

You save it in a variable, then use the variable for whatever you want.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Are you there??